# $ R$ is left-total if and only if $ \operatorname{Id}_A \subseteq R \circ R^{-1} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations

Proof:
$$R\;\text{ is  left-total } \Longleftrightarrow  \operatorname{Id}_A \subseteq R \circ R^{-1} $$

$R \subseteq A \times A  $
$ R \circ R^{-1} = \{(a,c) \mid \exists b \in A: aRb\; \text{ and } \; bR^{-1}c \} $

This is the third part of this exercise. The first were similar, where you had to prove something if and only if R is transitive. I managed to prove it but I'm struggling with the assignment above quite a bit.
Also could not find anything online, but because I'm German and my assignment is in German, I might not have been able to translate it correctly to find what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that $R$ left-total means: for every $a\in A$, there exists $b\in A$ such that $(a,b)\in R$.

Suppose $R$ satisfies $\mathit{Id}_A\subseteq R\circ R^{-1}$; then, for every $a\in A$, $(a,a)\in R\circ R^{-1}$, so there exists $b\in A$ with $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,a)\in R^{-1}$.

> In particular $(a,b)\in R$. Thus $R$ is left-total.

Conversely, suppose $R$ is left-total. Take $a\in A$: you want to prove that $(a,a)\in R\circ R^{-1}$. By assumption, there exists $b\in A$ such that $(a,b)\in R$.

> Then $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,a)\in R^{-1}$, so…

Comment: This is not homework I have to do, but it's preparation for my exam and you helped me understanding the proof, so thanks a lot. I would like to ask a couple of questions, if you don't mind:  
1.) You assumed what left-total means. I was wondering why I couldn't find anything, that was about left-total Relations. In Germany the property is called 'total'. What would you call it in English?  
2.) You proved the if and only if statement by assuming each side and follow the other side. In class we always did: Assume Side A and follow B; Assume not B follow not A. Is there a difference?

Comment: @Awesome36 I've never heard of “left-total” relations; that was just an educated guess. There is no difference in proving $A\implies B$ and $\lnot B\implies \lnot A$. One method for proving $A\iff B$ is proving $A\implies B$ and $\lnot A\implies \lnot B$, but the second part can also be proving that $B\implies A$.

Comment: Interesting.. Maybe that's why I could not find anything here, although I assumed the exercise was pretty common. Anyways, thanks a lot for helping me out. Any advice as I'm new to the site?

Comment: @Awesome36 Go forth and practice proofs! :-)